# A real JavaScript keyword or just a bug in Notepad++?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, object, notepad++

I use Notepad++ for web-development. I was coding in JavaScript when I found this weird thing. I named a variable as `private` (I knew it wasn't a reserved keyword in JavaScript). But as I typed, it turned blue (all the JavaScript keywords are shown blue in Notepad++). So I thought there'll also be `public`, `class` and `protected` keywords. And to my surprise, they also turned blue! So does it mean JavaScript has class-based object-oriented model along with the prototypical model? I checked the following code -

```
public class Foo {
    private bar;
}
```

But the console said - `SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word`.

**Question** - Does JavaScript support class-based object-oriented model or is it just a bug in Notepad++ or my syntax is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a [reserved keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) so that in future, this feature could be added without breaking existing code.

If you allowed `private`, then adding `private` feature to the language later would break any code that was using `private` as a normal identifier.

Comment: So will JavaScript introduce Class-based model in future?

Comment: @SandyLee I don't know, this is just a "just in case" thing.

Answer (score 1):

`private` and `public` are Java keywords and are reserved by JavaScript.

`class` is an ECMAScript reserved word.

For OO class based implementations in JavaScript, please see **[here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/javascript-tutorial-functions-and-classes.html)**